# Wrong entity ID exception in install script

Tags: eav, setup-script

I am trying to run this install script but I am getting an exception `Wrong entity ID`. Tried debugging through debugger but I am not much familiar with the EAV architecture of Magento, so got lost.

Here is the portion of my config.xml

```
<resources>
    <namespace_mymodule_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Namespace_Mymodule</module>
            <class>Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
            <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
    </namespace_mymodule_setup>
    <namespace_mymodule_write>
        <connection>
            <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
    </namespace_mymodule_write>
    <namespace_mymodule_read>
        <connection>
            <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
    </namespace_mymodule_read>
</resources>
```

I have defined the class by extending it from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup {

}
```

And finally my install script contents are:

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute( 'quote_payment', 'b_transaction_id', array() );
$installer->addAttribute( 'order_payment', 'b_transaction_id', array() );
$installer->addAttribute( 'invoice', 'b_transaction_id', array() );
$installer->addAttribute( 'creditmemo', 'b_transaction_id', array() );

$installer->endSetup();
```

What's the error about? And Its a possibility that this script ran earlier successfully from a different module (this one is a rewrite) but I am not sure if it has then how to check for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole EAV around Mage_Sales is not anymore EAV. To add new attributes "the EAV-way" you have to use the Sales Setup class, which takes carr of the flat table design.

Try to change the setup class to `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup`

What magento version are you using?

Comment: Awesome! It worked :) Can you also tell a bit on where it made the change in database, something that I can go checkout in the database?

Comment: The affected tables should be sales_flat_quote_payment, sales_flat_order_payment, sales_flat_invoice and sales_flat_creditmemo.

Answer (score 4):

People getting this error in Magento2:

This seems to be an issue with dependency order during setup:upgrade with custom attributes. In Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml, make sure to include a sequence tag for each of the modules your attributes depend on. If you're adding attributes to Products in your Setup/InstallData.php file, you need to include:

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Catalog" />
</sequence>
```

In between your module declaration